# Is this brake cable alignment correct or problematic?

Tags: disc-brake, cable-routing

I have a BB7 disc brake to fit to a CAAD10. Am I fitting this wrong or have I bought the wrong thing?

[image: bb7 caliper cable alignment]

It doesn't look like the brake cable lines up with the rubber bit - like this: 
[image]

I have not yet run the cables but it looks like they would need to bend considerably as they are supposed to come out of that hole in the frame.

I can post a pic of a different angle later, but how much bend on a brake cable is okay?

Will this be a problem? Am I fitting it wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is my disc brake caliper correctly mounted on the frame?](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/15137/is-my-disc-brake-caliper-correctly-mounted-on-the-frame)

Comment: @DWGKNZ while this is essentially the same question, the angles and cable alignment will differ per frame so what might work for that bike may not work for mine. I'd still like an answer specific to my issue if possible.

Comment: @Adam, then please edit your title to reflect exactly what you want to know. Yes-no questions are a poor fit here in general, but right now all anyone can say is "It's a brake. On a bike. Connect it up. Ride". Have you tried connecting the brake cable? What happened? If not, why not? Perhaps add a top-down view so we can see the problematic angle or offset that concerns you.

Comment: @Nui thanks. I have made some edits. I thought the pic was enough to show the problem but I'll post another from a top down view later

Comment: FWIW I have a tight-ish bend on my bike similar to how yours might end up and it hasn't been a problem. Albeit that bike is only about 8 or 9 years old, but I do ride it a fair bit and it doesn't go through brake cables or outers any faster than my other bikes. They have a similar, albeit gentler, curve in the second photo.

Comment: I note that your frame differs from the stock photo, and that you have a different model of caliper.  So it won't look exactly the same.  Your outer cable will require a smaller radius turn to get back into the frame hole.   From the photo, I can't tell it it will end up outside or inside the chainstay.  Either way, it should be fine.   If it were nearing a right-angle turn, I'd worry.

Comment: Other issue to be wary of is using bb7mtn with brifters. Bb7r (for road) uses a different amount of cable pull than bb7mtn. While not ideal it can work just will require finding the right solution online.

Comment: @DWGKNZ thanks for spotting and pointing this out. I'm actually going for normal shifters as I don't want drop bars on this bike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Frames and set us do differ so sometimes you can't use the built in cable routing without making the cable bend at an unrealistic angle. This can be resolved by leaving a bit more cable so it can (in your pic) loop a little under the chain stay and then probably miss out that cable route. However, saying that, looking at the pic the rubber housing makes the angle look particularly severe and it probably won't be that bad.

I would offer up the cable and see how it looks and if you are worried about it I would just use some tie wraps on that section.

Alternatively there may be a better brake that suites so check what brake came as standard and see if the angles look any different.

Answer (score 2):

Take a little bit longer housing (about 10mm) for the cable and let it a curve to bottom. It should fit perfectly.